LOG4J2 displays Hibernate logs and mine in development, but only Hibernate logs from the installed MSI (JavaFX 22 using Maven and jpackage for MSI)
My LOG4J2 logs are visible in development, but no longer when the application is installed via MSI in production.
The Hibernate logs are recorded in both cases, and in the correct file (the path is specified in the configuration file).
Here is my log4j2.xml configuration file:
<Configuration status="INFO" name="2024Log4j2Config">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:logs}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile
                name="RollingFile"
                fileName="${LOG_DIR}/app.log"
                filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm}--%i.log.gz"
                ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_DIR}">
                    <IfFileName glob="app.*.log.gz"/>
                    <IfLastModified age="P30D"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="DEBUG"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger level="INFO" name="fr.bla.fx2024" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="INFO"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

My Java Log class code :
    /**
     * Set the default logs' path inside a logs system property
     */
    private void setCurrentDefaultLogsPathInALog4j2SystemProperty() {
        System.setProperty("logs", logsFolderPath);
    }
    /**
     * Set the current Log4j2 configuration file's path
     */
    private void setCurrentLog4j2ConfigurationFilePath() {
        String log4j2ConfigurationPath = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(ResourcesPaths.getCONFIG_LOG4J2_PATH())).toExternalForm();
        Configurator.initialize("2024Log4j2Config", log4j2ConfigurationPath);
    }

I noticed that the getCONFIG_LOG4J2_PATH() path is different in development and in production, but I don't understand how Hibernate finds it and writes its data to it, and especially how to resolve this point:
Dev  : file:/C:/Users/MyUser/.../log4j2.xml
Prod : jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/MyOrganisation/app/MyApp.jar!/fr/bla/fx2024/config/log4j2.xml

I don't know if this is your issue.  When jpackage or jlink is used, they create special customized versions of the JRE.  When they do that, they strip stuff that won't be needed out.  Which is fine if you don't actually need it.  But sometimes you do (for example the cryptoki module used in SSL support).  Usually that is because the module code is optional and only loaded at runtime when it is actually needed and when the runtime was packaged it wasn't told it might be needed.

The solution (if you have a similar issue), is to identify the missing modules and add them, either by requiring them in the module definition or by binding services when you generate the runtime (using the --bind-services option).  This could be an issue you have, but it is more likely your path resolution logic is wrong.  Please provide a [mcve] to replicate.

You can remove a runtime packaging error from the equation by testing executing the jar files for the app as modules from the command line using the full java runtime, rather than the packaged one.  If it doesn't work, then that means that issue is not related to packaging.

You might avoid having to troubleshoot by changing the logging framework to logback+slf4j instead of log4j - of course that could be some work for you.  It might be quite tricky for you to create a [mcve] for this and then for somebody to replicate and debug this issue to assist you.

@jewelsea I have the same thing when launching the fat jar generated with maven-shade, so that's not a jpackage issue.
I moved to Logback ans I used the ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() method to load the configuration file as a stream. This method is designed to load resources from the classpath, including resources inside jar files.
try (InputStream inputStream = Log.class.getResourceAsStream(ResourcesPaths.getCONFIG_LOGBACK_PATH())) {
...

